# how to use a normal ssh key with tortoise/plink/pageant

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, tortoise-svn

I am normally a linux user and therefore I generated all my rsa-keypairs there. Now I have to use a windows system to do some work, and therefore need to get my repositories via ssh, but unfortunately pageant (which is [somehow a have-to](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto_logemann.html) if you use tortoise) won't accept my ssh key-files as they are no ppk files.

Any solutions, as I must not generate new key-pairs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is *no such thing* as "normal" keys. Neither format is more "normal" than the other.

You can convert the OpenSSL private keys to PuTTY `.ppk` format using PuTTYgen, which, like Pageant, is part of the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) package. Use the "Import OpenSSH key" command, then "Save private key".